# Android, MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, stores two images

Tags: android, mediastore

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Built-in Camera, using the extra MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT stores pictures twice (in my folder, and in the default)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341329/built-in-camera-using-the-extra-mediastore-extra-output-stores-pictures-twice)

I am using: `intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile("..path/filename.png") )` 
in conjunction the appropriate methods.

It works in that I do get an image stored in a file at the specified path. The problem is that it also stores the image in another date coded `filename` in `/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/`

Is there a way to prevent the creation of this unwanted second file?