# Android: Bitmap from Camera Intent retrieving wrong Height and Width Data

Tags: android

I am using `CameraIntent` in my Application but the photo in the app got different resolution from the photo that is saved on the SDCard.

I am using the following code:

```
            Intent mCameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            mCameraIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);
            startActivityForResult(mCameraIntent, mCameraRequest);


        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
        {
                if(requestCode == mCameraRequest)
                {
                    Bitmap photo = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");

                    int width = photo.getWidth();
                    int height = photo.getHeight();

                }
        }
```

The value of width is 320 and the value of height is 200, and on the SDCard the resolution of the photo is 2592x1552. I need the exact Width and Height in order to resize the photo for the desired resolution. What I am doing wrong? Are the `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` returning wrong values or?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341329/built-in-camera-using-the-extra-mediastore-extra-output-stores-pictures-twice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Bitmap` that you receive in `onActivityResult` is a thumbnail.

If you want to have access to the actual file, you should provide the URI where you want the image to be saved with the [EXTRA_OUTPUT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#EXTRA_OUTPUT) intent extra:

```
Intent mCameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
mCameraIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputUri);
mCameraIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);
startActivityForResult(mCameraIntent, mCameraRequest);
```

Answer (score 3):

From the javadoc of android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE

```
/** The caller may pass an extra EXTRA_OUTPUT to control where this image will be written. If
* the EXTRA_OUTPUT is not present, then a small sized image is returned as a Bitmap object    in
* the extra field. This is useful for applications that only need a small image. If the
* EXTRA_OUTPUT is present, then the full-sized image will be written to the Uri value of
* EXTRA_OUTPUT.
**/
```

As metionned in javadoc: you receive a **small** image. So I would suggest to use the EXTRA_OUTPUT and getting the size from the Bitmap stored on the sdcard. (see [BitmapFactory.Options](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html) to get only the size of the image)